Does there exist a non-rectangular polygon such that $3$ copies of it can be joined together (non-overlapping) to form a square?
For any even $n,$ there exists a non-rectangular polygon such that $n$ copies of it can be joined together (non-overlapping) to form a square.
I am wondering if this is also the case for odd $n,$ in particular, for $n=3.$
I imagine not, but then, how would you prove that it can never be done?
One idea is to look at the outside of the square and show that one side must belong to the non-rectangular polygon, and then argue that this is impossible. Or something.

The square version is Problem 875 in Crux. Solution in this issue. $\quad$ For $n = 3$, Maltby showed in 1992 that this wasn't possible for rectangles other than the 2 rectangular arrangements. (link to article). It is a bunch of side length, corner, angle chasing. $\quad$ This other article might be helpful.
